# My selectpicker doesn't display correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-selectpicker

My Selectpicker doesn't show on table. What is the error ? I don't know why don't show my full selectpicker.

[image]

its shown like that.

[image]

Comment: Please support your question with code snippet.

Comment: This looks like an overflow issue judging by the scrollbar on the right. Am I correct in thinking the scrollbar appears as soon as you open the selectpicker?